# HTML data attributes values. How to change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I have a div, which I can't edit. Is it possible to multiply the values of the data attribute?

Code:

```
<div class="reviews" data-page-opts="
   {
    showform:1,
    showsupport:0,
    postid:241,
    perpage:5,
    paginate:1,
    classes:reviews_in_content, wrapper:1,
    morelink:,
    on_postid:0,
    num:9999,
    hidecustom:0,
    snippet:0,
    hidereviews:0,
    hideresponse:0,
    ajax:0,
    thispage:1
   }
   ">
</div>
```

***Example***:
I want to multiply **thispage: *1*** by ***5*** or just to replace **1** with **5**. Can I do this with JavaScript/jQuery? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, there are a variety of things you can do here. Have you done any research or made any attempt?

Comment: I've searched, but never found how to multiply the values. Sorry if there is similar question.

Answer (score 0):

Use can use jQuery to get value of data first, and then use `JSON.parse()`, and then modify, after you modify, you can use `JSON.stringify();`
Here is example code:

`var data = $('div.reviews').attr('data-page-opts');
    var dataObj = JSON.parse(data);
    dataObj.ajax = 1;
    data = JSON.stringify(dataObj);
    $('div.reviews').attr('data-page-opts', data);`

Comment: The attribute does not contain JSON.